# dynamic options in select box using angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to add option dynamically to select box using angular.
For example, if quantity limit is 4 then options should be 1, 2, 3, 4.

This is what i have tried:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedQuantity">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option ng-repeat="n in range(1,edata.Products.QuantityLimit)" value="{{n}}">{{n}}</option>
                        </select>
```

Here QuantityLimit different for each select box.

Angular code:

```
$scope.range = function (min, max, step) {
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) input.push(i);
    return input;
};
```

this works as expected if i remove `ng-model="selectedQuantity"` from select. Is there any way to do this without removing `ng-model="selectedQuantity"`

Comment: _this works as expected if i remove ng-model="selectedQuantity" from select._ Care to elaborate?

Comment: Can you show the breakdown of this : `edata.Products.QuantityLimit`

Comment: @AlonEitan when i remove ng-model="selectedQuantity" from select I am initial option is 1; but with ng-model="selectedQuantity" initially no selected option in the select box.

Comment: @SandipIntrop You can add `ng-init="selectedQuantity = 1` to the select element, or set it in the controller: `$scope.selectedQuantity = 1;` (Prefered)

Comment: @AlonEitan      ng-init="selectedQuantity = 1" worked; Thanks a lot for your help. Please put the answer below, I'll accept it. Thanks once again.

Comment: @SandipIntrop Thanks, I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline `ngInit` directive to set an initial value to the model directly from the view:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedQuantity" ng-init="selectedQuantity = 1">
```

And of-course, set a default value from the controller:

```
$scope.selectedQuantity = 1;
```

Choose the one you like

Answer (score 0):

Try this embedding the options in the select tag itself using ng-options,

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="n for n in range(1,edata.Products.QuantityLimit)" ng-model="selectedQuantity">
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

The first option will be always 1, if you can you can shift it to controller.